# Why is Code Contract analysis not installed by default

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, code-contracts

We're just beginning a new project and we're keen to include testing from the ground up.

While we were looking at which unit test solution to use I came across Code Contracts which seem like they offer an easier way to check things like null parameter passing without having to write independent unit test methods.

One thing I am little confused about and makes me wary of investing heavily in Code Contract checks, is the fact that the analysis tool needs to be downloaded from DevLabs and isn't included in VS2012 by default.

What is the reason for this?

Additionally: It seems people are reporting that VS2012 support for Code Contract analysis seems flakey, why would be use Code Contracts if the analysis capabilities aren't very good?

Comment: I had issues a while back with CC in 2012 but those have been fixed in recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for VS2012, but it works perfectly fine for me in VS2010. There is a very minor conflict with Code Analysis in that a false alert is raised, but you simply switch off that Code Analysis rule and rely on the Code Contracts static checking (which is a lot more comprehensive).

Probably the best place to get the answer for your IDE integration is via the email address located on the [Code Contracts Website](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/default.aspx), however I suspect that because its a research project, not having it as an "official" part of the IDE provides the ability for more regular updates.